# DateTime condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a condition I want to select only the lines where the date field is 2h before at least but I can't find how to make this where clause.

The current date is:

> 2019-05-28 14:30:00

I have in database those line

> 2019-05-28 13:30:00
>
> 2019-05-28 10:30:00

I want to be able to catch the second one.

I could get all result one by one...turning them into timestamp...but I feel like I can do this in a simple sql request.

I was thinking about BETWEEN, but I don't see how it will worked in this case.

Thanks.

Issue solved:

If someone can post it as a response: We need a combinaison og DATE SUB and INTERVAL

```
SELECT * FROM `offer` WHERE updatedAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```

Comment: _where the date field is 2h before_ 2 hours before what?

Comment: Does you column REALLY contain `2019-28-05 14:30:00` i.e. `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS` because that is NOT a valid `DATE` or `DATETIME` column which is going to make ANY date or time querying Vastly more complex for you to code. **PS** Dont use VARCHAR to store Dates and Times!#

Comment: you can check on mysql intervals. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/

Comment: My mistake. It's a valid DateTime 05-28 and not 28-05

Comment: `SELECT * FROM  your_tabl WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze When I try this `SELECT * FROM app__offer WHERE updatedAt < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` ---> It says the key work INTERVAL and HOUR is unknown

Comment: @Minirock - Strange, it works for me